# How can I connect Flutter App with any other device using roslib dependency?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, ros

In roslib (https://pub.dev/packages/roslib/example) flutter package, there is a line such as:

```
Ros ros = Ros(url: 'ws://10.0.2.2:9090');
```

I am not sure if the url needs to be of the android emulator device or the device I am compiling the code on. Please help me out with any possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to be of the WebSocket service that you want to connect to. Are you facing any issues with it? If yes, please add that to the question as well so that, I can understand it better.